# How to assign ID attribute to UI form element component?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, ui-form

For example, I have a simple admin UI form with one text input field:

```
<field name="my_text" formElement="input">
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label>My Text</label>
    </settings>
</field>
```

How can I add ID attribute to it?

Comment: you may want to elaborate your question a bit more? the form you are showing here has not javascript whatsoever and I don't see what you are trying to do to be honest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea here, that Knockout.js generates ID *dynamically*.
Generated ID is available in a KO template, or in corresponding UI component's javascript file as `uid` variable.

In order to customize form element component in admin you can use your own *template* or *ui component* that extends `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract` class.

For example, we have a text input component. And we need to use element ID in some other attribute.
At first, you should define custom **template** for a component:

```
<field name="my_text" formElement="input" template="template="Your_Module/form/custom-input">
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label>My Text</label>
    </settings>
</field>
```

Then in a template it's possible to access element ID attribute in `data-bind` attribute:

```
<button data-bind="attr: {'custom-attribute': 'dynamic_attribute_example' + uid}"></button>
```

In this example we set dynamic attribute `custom-attribute` for the button.